# Get a list of all PostScript dictionaries

Tags: postscript

Is there a way to get a complete list of dictionaries contained within in an unknown PostScript environment? The reason i need this is that i want to look into into potential vendor-specific or user-defined dictionaries as well as into the documented ones (`systemdict, statusdict, userdict, currentdict`, etc.).

Is there mabybe something like `dicstack forall`? Or do all dicts maybe need to register somewhere (e.g. in `systemdict`) or keep a copy of themselves in `systemdict`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dictstack` operator will fill an array with the contents of the dict stack. (Use `countdictstack` to find out how big the array needs to be.) And then, yes, you can iterate through this array with `forall`. You can traverse through the contents of individual dictionaries similarly.

Do you need just names, or a "full path" to every named dictionary?

You may want to look at my old set of [dictstack tools](http://web.archive.org/web/20160404161545/https://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=ds.ps&can=2&q=).

Comment: Names are totally fine. The dictstack tools was exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot!